# Align table exclusively to plus-minus signs without taking the decimal point into account

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I would like to align my table the following way:

Arsen______0,63+-0,12__________18 +-12
Blei________11,7+-0,6__________109 +-9

As you can see, I don't want to have any space between the \pm sign and the numbers, even if some of the numbers have decimal places (the latter should be completely ignored)

How can I achieve this with my table? I couldn't get the job done using sinunitx.

```
    \documentclass[listof=totoc, %Abildungsverzeichnis, Bildverz.)
            twoside, openright,
            bibliography=totocnumbered,%num. L.Verz.
            numbers=noenddot]  %keine Punkte nach Section-Nummerierung
            {scrreprt} %Dokumentklasse
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=20mm,
            footskip=24pt] %Länge zwischen Text und Seitenzahl
            {geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Tabelle1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Element} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{TWP/f}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Pavement}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Road Side}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Elbe}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Freiberger Mulde}} & \textbf{Saale} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Arsen*} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}0,63 \pm 0,12 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}18 \pm 12 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}15,7 \pm 0,6 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}38 \pm 6 & n. b.  & n. b. \\
    \textbf{Blei} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}11,7 \pm 0,6 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}109 \pm 9 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}172 \pm 18 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}109 \pm 26 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}1900 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}120 \\
    \textbf{Cadmium} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}0,23 \pm 0,06 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}0,67 \pm 0,12 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}1,0 \pm 0,0 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}5,2 \pm 0,9  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}440 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}6,1 \\
    \textbf{Chrom} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}3,20 \pm 0,27 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}242 \pm 17 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}344 \pm 9 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}112 \pm 19 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}260 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}96 \\
    \textbf{Kupfer} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}18 \pm 3 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}510 \pm 100 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}1047 \pm 6 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}99 \pm 27  & n. b. & n. b. \\
    \textbf{Nickel} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}4,9 \pm 0,5 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}122 \pm 11 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}88 \pm 3 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}50 \pm 5 & n. b. & n. b. \\
    \textbf{Zink} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}10430 \pm 80 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}980 \pm 28 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}2250 \pm 40 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}950 \pm 190 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}20100 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .941}110 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code does not compile. However you could use two different columns for values and errors and place the +- sign in between, like in this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/802f9a81-9db8-4183-bdab-177bba39579d/view-source

Comment: Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package. It exploits the fact that there's no `.` (dot, aka full stop) symbol in the four columns in question (other than in the `\cellcolor` directives). I've converted all instances of `\pm` to `.` and have defined a new column type, `d`, which converts instances of `.` back to `\pm`. That way, the column's contents will be centered on the `\pm` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, %Abildungsverzeichnis, Bildverz.)
            twoside, openright,
            bibliography=totocnumbered,%num. L.Verz.
            numbers=noenddot]  %keine Punkte nach Section-Nummerierung
            {scrreprt} %Dokumentklasse
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=20mm,
            hmargin=20mm, % set as needed
            footskip=24pt] %Länge zwischen Text und Seitenzahl
            {geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% new code:
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{\:\pm\:}{-1}} % for columns 2 to 5
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}         % for columns 6 & 7
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{icomma}  % treat commas in math mode as decimal markers

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % for a less-cramped look
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption} \label{tab:addlabel}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{d} CC }
  \hline
  \textbf{Element} & 
  \mc{\textbf{TWP/f}} & 
  \mc{\textbf{Pavement}} & 
  \mc{\textbf{Road Side}} & 
  \mc{\textbf{Elbe}} & 
  \textbf{Freiberger} & 
  \textbf{Saale} \\[-3pt]
    & & & & & \textbf{Mulde} \\
  \hline
  \textbf{Arsen*}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}0,63 . 0,12 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}18 . 12 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}15,7 . 0,6 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}38 . 6 & \mc{n.b.}  & \mc{n.b.}\\
  \textbf{Blei}    & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}11,7 . 0,6 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}109 . 9 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}172 . 18 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}109 . 26 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}1900 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}120 \\
  \textbf{Cadmium} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}0,23 . 0,06 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}0,67 . 0,12 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}1,0 . 0,0 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}5,2 . 0,9  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}440 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}6,1 \\
  \textbf{Chrom}   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}3,20 . 0,27 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}242 . 17 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}344 . 9 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}112 . 19 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}260 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}96 \\
  \textbf{Kupfer}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}18 . 3 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}510 . 100 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}1047 . 6 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}99 . 27  & \mc{n.b.} & \mc{n.b.} \\
  \textbf{Nickel}  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}4,9 . 0,5 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .871,  .216}122 . 11 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .816,  .314}88 . 3 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}50 . 5 & \mc{n.b.} & \mc{n.b.} \\
  \textbf{Zink}    & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}10430 . 80 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}980 . 28 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}2250 . 40 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .6,  0}950 . 190 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}20100 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .941}110 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Hey Mico, I have another question in which I need some help. I am using a "." as a "thousand separator" with siunitx. E. g. 1.000,2. Do you know how I can achieve that Latex shows me those dots in the outpout without loosing or adding an extra \pm?

Comment: @YannikK - Do I understand you correctly as saying that you're combining, or are trying to combine, the capabilities of the `D` column type provided by the `dcolumn` package and of the `S` column type provided by the `siunitx` package? Please advise. Please also consider posting an entirely new query, which will be seen by many more people and may thus generate a better solution than what I might be able to come up with on my own.

Comment: @YannikK - I must confess that I find a particular element of your follow-up comment to be quite confusing. Specifically, why are you providing a thousands-separator symbol on *input*? The `siunitx` package is set up to provide a suitable thousands-separator in the *output*.